# How to redirect to specific BLOG Dashboard (after login to Multi-Site)

Tags: login, dashboard

I use Multi-Site at `example.com`.
 Is there any simple method to redirect users  to specific blog dashboard? for example, when I login at:

`example.com/wp-login.php`
instead of default redirection to

`example.com/wp-admin` I want to be redirected to

`example.com/sub-site/wp-admin`

Answer (score 1):

please see this it working fine for me :)

```
function uop_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user  ) {
    return ( is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) ? admin_url() : site_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'uop_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
// redirecting to chosen language dashboard 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'admin_redirect', 10, 3 );    //
function admin_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if(isset($_POST['redirect_to']) && $_POST['redirect_to']==network_home_url().'wp-admin/') {
        //is there a user to check?
        if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            return network_home_url().'eng/wp-admin';
        }
    }
    else { return $redirect_to; }
}
```